# loops inside jsx in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to generate 3 `span` inside `div` using react, here's my code.

```
export class Test extends React.Component<undefined, undefined> {
  render() {
    const list = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
    const body = (
      list.map(s => {
        <span>s</span>
      })
    )
    return (
      <div>
        {body}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

However it didn't work. There's no tag inside `div` generated, why? Is there anything wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `{}` you're indicating a regular JS syntax, while in this case you're trying to use JSX syntax so you should wrap it in `()` or in this implied return you can just ignore it.

```
export class Test extends React.Component<undefined, undefined> {
  render() {
    const list = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
    const body = (
      list.map(s => 
        <span key={s}>s</span>
      )
    )
    return (
      <div>
        {body}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I vote for your answer as it's the cleanest, but you should explain why removing the `{}` eliminates the need of `return`.

Comment: Yeah sorry. If @Searene you want to read more about `map` in combination with jsx and es6, there are a lot of helpful tutorials and documentation. Also I forgot to mention, that you should provide a `key` to your tags inside the `map` like here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#javascript-expressions-as-children

Answer (score 4):

You need to return the values. This should work:

```
export class Test extends React.Component<undefined, undefined> {
      render() {
        const list = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
        const body = list.map(s => {
            return <span>s</span>
          })
        return (
          <div>
            {body}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use "concise body" or the usual "block body" for your map methods callback function in ES6 arrow functions.

In a concise body, only an expression is needed, and an implicit return is attached. In a block body, you must use an explicit return statement.

Concise body

```
export class Test extends React.Component<undefined, undefined> {
  render() {
    const list = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
    const body = (
      list.map(s => 
        <span key={s}>s</span>
      )
    )
    return (
      <div>
        {body}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Block body:

```
export class Test extends React.Component<undefined, undefined> {
  render() {
    const list = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
    const body = (
      list.map((s) => 
        {return <span key={s}>s</span>}
      )
    )
    return (
      <div>
        {body}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

For more information please refer that page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
export class Test extends Component {

    renderRows(){
        const lists = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
        lists.map(list=>{
            return (
                <span key={list}>{list}</span>
            );
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderRows()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```